# meshes not really responding to armature's animation

Tags: animation, rigging, distort

I have a character made with multiple meshes(They aren't connected, the meshes can move separately) I'm trying to animate it but one of the meshes wont bend with the armature while the other does, but the other does, but distorts a little when it bends. How do I solve both problems?

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Please find a way to illustrate, concisely, what you want, what you've got, and the difference. (Preferably with screen-shots). Your text can mean too many different things, to answer precisely. A share, as suggested, will help us find possible fixes for you.

Comment: i fixed the mesh.